# How to avoid UI hanging with Invoke?

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

The following code makes UI thread hanging.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(Func);
        t.Start();
    }

    private void Func()
    {
        this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            while (true);
        }));
    }
```

I'd like to have `Func()` invoked in a different working thread without any UI thread freezing every time I click the button.

What would be the best workaround?

Comment: why you put  `while (true);` in `Invoke` method, you don't have any code changing UI, it will block UI thread,

Comment: I'd like to put some code changing UI in the loop. I just elided those code in the loop to make it look simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your code, `while(true)` is running on UI thread, that is the reason which blocks your UI.

Put `while(true)` out of `Invoke` method, so whenver you want to change UI, put the block of code changing UI inside `Invoke`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(Func);
    t.Start();
}

private void Func()
{
    while(true)
    {
       this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            textBox.Text = "abc";
        }));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This will help me a lot. Is there any way to accept both answers?

Answer (score 2):

The Func() codes does run on a non-UI thread.  However, the `this.Invoke` then executes the Action on the UI thread!.

Try something like this:

```
void Func()
{
     // Do some work.

     // Update the UI (must be on UI thread)
     this.Invoke(Action) (() =>
     {
        // Update the UI.
     }));
 }
```

I might be better to use the `BeginInvoke` method.  This way the non-UI thread is not waiting around for the UI thread to do the Action.

Also, you have no Exception catching or progress reporting logic.  I recommend looking at the `BackgroundWorker` class; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx.

```
void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
   worker.DoWork += (s,e) =>
   {
       // Do some work.
   };
   worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s,e) =>
   {
       // Update the UI.
   }
   worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```